# Mining node stops working frequently

Tags: blockchain, ether, mining, microsoft-azure

hello guys,

i have created a private Ethereum blockchain network on Microsoft azure which has one transaction node and two mining nodes with configuration-For transaction node the ram is 8gb and one of the mining node has 8gb and the other has 7gb of ram. The issue happening is, One of the mining node is going down frequently such that even if the other mining node exist for working it returns error i.e the transaction doesn't get committed. I tried restarting the node several times, But after sometime it again fails. Im new this Blockchain concepts- any help would be really appreciated

Comment: any stack trace?

Comment: @Kay see actually i'm new to this, if you could tell me how can i check if there's any stacktrace?

Comment: output logs of you node , depends on how you started your node

Comment: ok i can get this by using the command geth.log right?

Comment: But i should get the log before the node stopped working then only there would be a clue right?